# Removing decimal from line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

my year data when display on a table its a whole number but when I input it into a line chart under the x axis it splits itself in different time of the year. Could anyone help me sort it into just the year itself?

Here's my current code:

```
 df.plot( x = "Year", kind="line", figsize = (10,5), legend = True)
 plt.ticklabel_format(style="plain", axis="y")
 plt.xlabel("Year")
 plt.ylabel("Profit")
 plt.title("Yearly Profit")
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Create an axis instance ax, plot your df, and then use `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify that the column `Year` is `datetime` object:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y')
```

Output:
[image]